# hover on dynamically created list

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a menu with a list of items created dynamically using javascript.
They have different colour and country attributes created using setAttribute.

```js
$("#menuList a").hover(
  function() {
    var countryName = $(this).attr('country');
    var fruitColour = $(this).attr('colour');
    $('#toshow').append($("countryName \n fruitColour"));
  },
  function() {}
);
```

```css
.toshow {
  display: none;
}

#menuList a:hover div.toshow {
  top: 0;
  right: 0;
  display: block;
  position: absolute;
  z-index: 99999;
  background: red;
  width: 200px;
  height: 100px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul class="menubar" id="menuList">
  <li><a href="#" country="US" colour="green">Watermelon</a></li>
  <li><a href="#" country="Australia" colour="green">Grapes</a></li>
  <li><a href="#" country="null" colour="null">Strawberry</a></li>
  <li><a href="#" country="null" colour="null">Blueberry</a></li>
</ul>


<div class="toshow" id="toshow"></div>
```

Here, I want to have a separated hidden div (display at top right of the page or next to the menuList) that does not have any content until any of the `<a>` tag being hovered, and show its responding two attributes until no more mouse hovered.

The code does not have errors. But I don't see anything in red when the mouse hovered through the list. Is it possible to achieve what I am looking for?

Comment: So you have that list and when i hover it you want to show the attributes of the hovered elements somewhere else right? Why would anything be red?

Comment: `The code does not have errors. But I don't see anything in red when the mouse hovered` first you're not toggling the display of the div, and second `$("countryName \n fruitColour")` this is  wrong i think i'm not familiar with jQuery, just remove `$()`

Comment: @Heady, because I've set the div to shows up in red with those attributes of hovered elements inside the red div.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the [`mouseout`](https://api.jquery.com/mouseout/) event to hide the `toshow` div with [`hide`](https://api.jquery.com/hide/) as you leave a list element. And at each [`hover`](https://api.jquery.com/hover/) event, you can change the html of `toshow` to the values of the `li` element which the user is hovering over and use [`show`](https://api.jquery.com/show/) to display it.

Also make sure you attach the event handlers *after* you've inserted the html of the dynamically generated list.:

```js
function displayGeneratedList() {
  $('#menuList').html(`
    <li><a href="#" country="US" colour="green">Watermelon</a></li>
    <li><a href="#" country="Australia" colour="green">Grapes</a></li>
    <li><a href="#" country="null" colour="null">Strawberry</a></li>
    <li><a href="#" country="null" colour="null">Blueberry</a></li>
  `);
  $("#menuList a").hover(function() {
    var countryName = $(this).attr('country');
    var fruitColour = $(this).attr('colour');
    $('#toshow').html(`${countryName}<br>${fruitColour}`).show();
  });
  $('#menuList a').mouseout(function() {
    $('#toshow').hide();
  });
}

$(document).ready(function() {
  displayGeneratedList();
});
```

```css
#menuList {
  display: inline-block;
}

.toshow {
  display: none;
  float: right;
  background: maroon;
  width: 200px;
  height: 100px;
  padding: 5px;
  color: white
}
```

```html
<ul class="menubar" id="menuList">
</ul>

<div class="toshow" id="toshow"></div>

<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: Thank you @slider for the help! I tried, but no errors with no new div shows up anywhere on screen, I tried to adjust the css, adding z-index or stuff still no show. Initially there is a function generating the list, so I added the jquery in it, same, then i tried to put it in a new function then have the document.ready to call it, no show, also same when I put the contents of the function in the document.ready , still the same. do you think bootstrap may affects the output? tho i dont think it is possible.

Comment: @Santa I don't think Bootstrap should be a problem. I can't really help you much without seeing your code. Perhaps you can compare what's different in the snippet. One thing to be very careful of is that you should attach the event listeners to `menuList` *after* you add it to the page.

Comment: oops ! I am new to this, does that means the hover&mouseout should be added immediately after <li> being updated? I did it separately because I didnt want to affect the function that purely serve to update data to menulist. Allow me to try my last luck, I have an index.php with the <ul> and new generated <div> tag. Then the style.css file, bootstrap to decorate menu list, and for 'toshow'. Lastly, the main.js, with the function {#menulist to add <li> to list} at above of file and document.ready function with the 'hover & mouseout' at bottom. Do you spot any problem in these ?

Comment: @Santa Doesn't look problematic. However, I'm not sure if you're *calling* the hover and mouseout code after you insert your `<li>`. I would recommend that you put that hover and mouseout code inside a function (like `function doHoverAndMouseout() {...}`) and *call* that function after each time you add new `<li>` elements.

Comment: Thank you @slider for the detailed explanation and helpful comment ! I've already got what i want by changing the code placement. :)